# grouping with complex "selection"

Tags: grouping, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is the source XML:

```
<root>
  <!-- a and b have the same date entries, c is different -->
  <variant name="a">
    <booking>
      <date from="2017-01-01" to="2017-01-02" />
      <date from="2017-01-04" to="2017-01-06" />
    </booking>
  </variant>
  <variant name="b">
    <booking>
      <date from="2017-01-01" to="2017-01-02" />
      <date from="2017-01-04" to="2017-01-06" />
    </booking>
  </variant>
  <variant name="c">
    <booking>
      <date from="2017-04-06" to="2017-04-07" />
      <date from="2017-04-07" to="2017-04-09" />
    </booking>
  </variant>
</root>
```

I'd like to group the three variants so that each variants with same `@from` and `@to` in each date should be grouped together.

My attempt is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <variants>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="for $i in variant return $i" group-by="booking/date/@from">
      <group>
        <xsl:attribute name="cgk" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"></xsl:copy-of>
      </group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </variants>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this gives too many groups. (How) is this possible to achieve?

Comment: what's the output your getting?

Comment: So which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? Might be easier with Saxon 9.8 or any other XSLT 3.0 processor and a`composite` grouping key. Also what would happen for a `variant` with the same `date` element, but in a different order? Does the order matter?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Currently I am using Saxon-HE 9.4.0.2J, but I can update easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [composite key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-grouping-key) and XSLT 3.0 you could use

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <variants>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="variant" group-by="booking/date/(@from, @to)" composite="yes">
            <group key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </variants>
</xsl:template>
```

which should group any `variant` elements together which have the same descendant `date` element sequence.

XSLT 3.0 is supported by Saxon 9.8 (any edition) or 9.7 (PE and EE) or a 2017 release of Altova XMLSpy/Raptor.

Using XSLT 2.0 you could concatenate all those date values with `string-join()`:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <variants>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="variant" group-by="string-join(booking/date/(@from, @to), '|')">
            <group key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </variants>
</xsl:template>
```

Like the XSLT 3.0 solution, it only groups `variant` with the same sequence of `date` descendants, I am not sure whether that suffices or whether you might want to sort any `date` descendants first before computing the grouping key. In the XSLT 3 case you could do that easily with

```
       <xsl:for-each-group select="variant" group-by="sort(booking/date, (), function($d) { xs:date($d/@from), xs:date($d/@to) })!(@from, @to)" composite="yes">
```

inline (although that leaves 9.8 HE behind as it does not support function expressions/higher order functions, so there you would need to move the sorting to your own user-defined `xsl:function` and in there use `xsl:perform-sort`).

Comment: Awesome! I have tried the `composite="yes"` on my simple test cases and there it works fine. I will try to apply it to the more complex "real world" data and report back.

Comment: I whish I could give you more than one upvote! Thanks again. I really love to see other solutions that inspire me to read and try out more. I came across XSLT/XPath 3 several times, but never had a good reason to try them out.